Finding the general solution to the given differential equation
I want to find the solution to the following differential equation:
$$y'=-\frac{4x+3y-1}{3x+4y+1}$$
I use the substitutions $x=s+1$ and $y=u-1$ to obtain
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{ds}=\frac{-4(s+1)-3(u-1)+1}{3(s+1)+4(u-1)+1}=\frac{-4s-3u}{3s+4u}.$$
If I now further substitute $z=\frac{u}{s}$ this yields
$$\frac{du}{ds}=s\frac{dz}{ds}+z=\frac{-4s-3zs}{3s+4zs}$$
$$\frac{dz}{ds}=\frac{1}{s}\frac{-4s-3zs-3zs-4sz^2}{3s+4zs}=\frac{-4-6z-4z^2}{s(3+4z)}$$
This is now a seperable equation so I can integrate both sides
$$-\int \frac{3+4z}{4+6z+4z^2}dz = \int \frac{1}{s}ds.$$
By substituting $w=4z^2+6z+4$ I can solve the first integral
$$\int \frac{3+4z}{4+6z+4z^2}dz=\int \frac{3+4z}{w}\frac{dw}{2(4z+3)}=\frac{1}{2} \ln|4z^2+6z+4|$$
So this gives me
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln|4z^2+6z+4| = \ln|s|+C_1$$
and after resubstituting z, s and u
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln\left|4\left(\frac{u}{s}\right)^2+6\frac{u}{s}+4\right| = \ln|s|+C_1$$
$$-\frac{1}{2} \ln\left|4\left(\frac{y+1}{x-1}\right)^2+6\frac{y+1}{x-1}+4\right| = \ln|x-1|+C_1$$
And after putting in some further work I get
$$\ln\left|4\left(\frac{y+1}{x-1}\right)^2+6\frac{y+1}{x-1}+4\right| = -2\ln|x-1|+C_2$$
$$4\left(\frac{y+1}{x-1}\right)^2+6\frac{y+1}{x-1}+4 = C_3\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$$
Now at this point I am pretty certain that I made a mistake, because even if I keep going and find en explicit expression for $y(x)$ it doesn't match the one wolfram alpha gives me. And if I go through the pain of calculating the derivative of my calculated solution and plug it into the initial differential equation, it doesn't work out. So I must have made a mistake along the way, but I cannot seem to find it. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

When you say it does not match WA, in what sense does it not match? Can you confirm it is truly different form WA? As opposed to just being algebraically equivalent but written differently?

yeah WA told me it's diffferent actually. And I don't see any way to bring it into the correct form

separable equation

I think it is a match. Take your result and clear denominators:
$$4(y+1)^2+6(y+1)(x-1)+4(x-1)^2-C_3=0$$
Now apply the quadratic formula to solve for $y+1$:
$$\begin{align}
y+1
&=\frac{-6(x-1)\pm\sqrt{36(x-1)^2-16\left[4(x-1)^2-C_3\right]}}{8}\\
&=-\frac34(x-1)\pm\frac14\sqrt{9(x-1)^2-4\left[4(x-1)^2-C_3\right]}\\
&=-\frac34(x-1)\pm\frac14\sqrt{4C_3-7(x-1)^2}\\
y&=-\frac34x-\frac14\pm\frac14\sqrt{4C_3-7(x-1)^2}
\end{align}$$
Meanwhile WA gives me:
$$y(x) = \frac14(-3 x - 1) \pm \frac12 \sqrt{c_1 + 8 (x/4 - x^2/2) + 1/4 (3 x + 1)^2}$$
Multiply by $4$ inside that radical and $\frac12$ outside:
$$y(x) = \frac14(-3 x - 1) \pm \frac14 \sqrt{4c_1 + 8 (x - 2x^2) + (3 x + 1)^2}$$
They are starting to look the same. I'll let you finish confirming that but I confirmed it without writing it down. Note that the $C_3$ I have is not the same as the $c_1$ from WA, but they differ by a constant.
